# Rails 5, Added action controller don't render correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added two new actions at my controller users

```
def show
end

def setting
end

def myhome
end
```

and the route in route.rb

```
resources :users do
   collection do
      get 'myhome'
   end
   member do
      get 'setting
   end
end
```

Also in users views i've added the pages `'setting.html.erb'` and `'myhome.html.erb'`

Now, if i browse `'/users/1/setting'` i see the correct page, but if i browse `'users/myhome'` i see the `show.html.erb` page.

Really i don't understand.

Comment: please add your rake routes for users

Comment: try using `myhome_users_path` to navigate to that view.

Comment: `<%= link_to "My Home", myhome_users_path %>`

Comment: @Ido Traini, have you tried this?

Comment: @Sravan it open the "show.html.erb" page.

Comment: @Shefalee , in the route i have: myhome_users GET /users/myhome(.:format) users#myhome

Comment: do you also want show action?

Comment: I have also a show action that is correctly displayed if i browse '/users/1/'

Comment: do you really want to show this way

Comment: @nifCody i don't understand your question.

Comment: Show the whole route.rb file

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is easy.
In route.rb you need to <del>put the generic resources :users after the customized routes</del> , so:

```
resources :users do
   get 'myhome', as: collection
   get 'setting', as: member
end
```

Edit: this route also include the REST standard route.
in this way the action get 'myhome' will not be 'interpretated' as show

Comment: also remove this resources :users unnecessary